# Sharepoint 2013 Hosted App execute javascript on all pages load

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, hosted-app, sharepoint-jsom

I would like to know if it's possible to have a SP 2013 Hosted app that injects a piece of Javascript that gets executed on every page load.

For the sake of simplicity, imagine that I want to create an App that on every page load of the SP Site displays a `alert('Hello world!');`

I don't want to have a Remote Web, pure and simple Hosted App that can be added by anyone simply by picking it from the SP Store.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the javascript using a custom action script link as @AlexCode suggests but the app will require `web - full control` permissions. I can't remember where I adapted this code from while I was looking into add-in development. Also this is for POC only you should probably look to make it more robust before using it in a live environment.

App.js contents

```
(function(undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var actions, web, context, hostContext, actionDescription;
    console.log('running function');
    // getQueryStringParameter: method to retrieve query string parameter values
    var getQueryStringParameter = function(param) {

            var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
            var length = params.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i = i + 1) {
                var singleParam = params[i].split('=');
                if (singleParam[0] == param) {
                    return singleParam[1];
                }
            }
        };

    // inject: method to return as a string the js that will be ran by the custom action
    var inject = function() {
            debugger;
            var scriptToRun;

            scriptToRun += '(function (){' +
                    'var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];' +                    
                    'var script = document.createElement("script");' +
                    'script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(alert("hello world")));' +                  
                    'elem.appendChild(script);' +
                '}());';

            return scriptToRun;
        };

    var success = function() {
        alert('Done');
    }

    var fail = function() {
        alert('Failed');
    }

    // unprovision: removes the custom action and the JavaScript file
    var unprovision = function() {
            context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl')));
            // load the custom actions from the host web
            actions = hostContext.get_web().get_userCustomActions();
            context.load(actions);
            web = hostContext.get_web();
            context.load(web);
            context.executeQueryAsync(unprovisionEx, fail);
        };

    // unprovisionEx: method to remove the custom action
    var unprovisionEx = function() {
            var enumerator = actions.getEnumerator();
            var removeThese = [];
            // find the custom action
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var action = enumerator.get_current();
                if (action.get_description() == actionDescription && action.get_location() == 'ScriptLink') {
                    // add it to a temporary array (we cannot modify an enumerator while enumerating)
                    removeThese.push(action);
                }
            }
            // do the actual removal of the custom action
            var length = removeThese.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                removeThese[i].deleteObject();
                delete removeThese[i];
            }

            context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);
        };


    // provisionScriptLink: method that adds the custom action
    var provisionScriptLink = function() {
            var enumerator = actions.getEnumerator();
            var removeThese = [];
            // check if the custom action already exists, if it does then remove it before adding the new one
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var action = enumerator.get_current();
                if (action.get_description() == actionDescription && action.get_location() == 'ScriptLink') {
                    removeThese.push(action);
                }
            }

            var length = removeThese.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                removeThese[i].deleteObject();
                delete removeThese[i];
            }

            // create the custom action
            var newAction = actions.add();
            // the 'description' is what we'll use to uniquely identify our custom action
            newAction.set_description(actionDescription);
            newAction.set_location('ScriptLink');
            newAction.set_scriptBlock(inject());

            newAction.update();
            context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);
        };

    // provision: starts with uploading the JavaScript file to the host we, once done it will continue with the provisionScriptLink() method
    var provision = function() {
            context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl')));
            // load the custom actions from the host web
            actions = hostContext.get_web().get_userCustomActions();
            context.load(actions);
            web = hostContext.get_web();
            context.load(web);

            context.executeQueryAsync(provisionScriptLink, fail);
        };


    document.getElementById("add").onclick = provision;

}());
```

Default.apsx content

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>

<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />

</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    Page Title
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

    <div>
       <button type="button" value="add" name="add" id="add">Add</button>
    </div>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server">
    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a custom master page to the host site from app site via javascript. Anyway the host site must use the new master page.

You can see [this article](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/05/sp2013-host-web-apps-provisioning-files.html) for more info

Comment: If I understood it well, that's not an option. I, as a SP Hosted App provider, have no control over the Host Web and I can't force anyone to do that.
I believe the way is through a CustomAction ScriptLink but I'm not sure how.